# Using Rpi python and MCP3008 ADC to read flame (RGB) sensor data for FFT analysis

Tags: sensor, spi, analog-to-digital, mcp3008

I have an IR pyroelectic flame sensor which detects flames within the 8-10hz of flame flicker.
I am new to the ADC world so any help is very appreciated.

Documentation: https://pyreos.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Pyreos-Analog-TO-Flame-Sensor-One-Channel.pdf

I have the py0573 which has a bandpass filter for CO2 spectrum. According to the company's algorithm recommendation, I basically need to plot/detect FFT (Fast Fourier transform) bins from the 5-15hz frequency to determine a "flame" exists on the FOV of the sensor.

In order for me to read the signal from the half-rail, I installed a MCP3008 to my RPi model 4 and set the signal to CH0 of the ADC. I also included a .1uf decoupling capacitor.

Using the below code, I am able to get some readings from the sensor, but I am unsure if this sampling rate is setup correctly or not.

Questions:

1. How do I setup the read from the ADC within the 8-10hz range?
2. Is there a way to plot this with FFT? Do I need FFT or can I determine
   the total sum values from ADC to indicate a "flame"?
3. Is the frequency setup basically the loop speed of Python or the
   **spi.max_speed_hz**  option?
4. Am I converting the raw ADC values correctly using numpy interp?
5. If the sensor has a max 10hz frequency then I need to double that for my sample rate?
6. Should I be using Adafruit's **adafruit-circuitpython-mcp3xxx** package instead?

With the below code, I am able to see the values change when I light a flicker match but its a bit inconsistent and only changes when the flame is flickering and not when its still.

```
import spidev 
from numpy import interp
import time
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

# Start SPI connection
spi = spidev.SpiDev() # Created an object
spi.open(0,0)   



# Read MCP3008 data
def analogInput(channel, hz):
  spi.max_speed_hz = hz
  adc = spi.xfer2([1,(8+channel)<<4,0])
  data = ((adc[1]&3) << 8) + adc[2]
  return data

data_list=list()
init_time = datetime.datetime.now()



while True:
    
    
    output1 = analogInput(0, 1000000)
    output1 = interp(output1, [0, 1023], [0, 100])
    
    data_list.append(output1)
    if init_time < datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=2):
        
        print("min" + str(min(data_list)))
        print("max" + str(max(data_list)))
        print("avg" + str(sum(data_list)/len(data_list)))
        data_list=list()
        init_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        
        
    time.sleep(.001)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120718/discussion-on-question-by-georgethecat-using-rpi-python-and-mcp3008-adc-to-read).

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

*How to use Rpi python MCP3008 ADC to help analyse flame flicker signals?*

---

[image: pyreos schematic]

*Notes*

1. A py0573 bandpass filter is used for CO2 spectrum
2. To determine if a "flame" exists on the FOV of the sensor, the vendor recommends a plot/detect FFT bins from the 5-15hz frequency.

---

*Electrical Characteristics*

1. Max. Voltage (+V) = 8.0 V
2. Min. Voltage (+V) = 2.7 V
3. Output voltage normalised around mid-rail
4. Time Constant = ~12 ms
5. Op-Amp with 10 GΩ feedback resistor

---

***Answer***

*Part 1 - Using MCP3008 to read raw data*

First thing first is to prepare 1,024 flame sensor readings for FFT. (See Reference 6 and Appendix B below for more details.)

[image: FFT Raw Data]

---

*/ to continue , ...*

---

***References***

(1) [Thin Film Pyroelectric Flame Sensor - PY-ITV-FLAME–TO39(2+1) R5.2 - Pyreos](https://pyreos.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Pyreos-Analog-TO-Flame-Sensor-One-Channel.pdf)

(2) [MCP3008 SPI 2.7V 8-Channel 10-Bit A/D Converters - MicroChip](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21295d.pdf)

(3) [Rpi Reading MCP3008 10 bit ADC Result Problem - Rpi SE 2019may22](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98867/rpi-reading-mcp3008-10-bit-adc-result-problem)

(4) [Flame Detector - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame_detector)

(5) [Tips To Select The Right Flame Detector - Edward Naranjo, Emerson Automation Solutions 2019mar06](https://www.chemicalprocessing.com/articles/2019/tips-to-select-the-right-flame-detector/)

(6) [AN0125 Application Note: Sample Flame Detection Ratio Based Algorithm - Pyreos](https://pyreos.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/AN0125-Sample-Flame-Detection-Ratio-Based-Algorithm.pdf)

(7) [Pyreos Evaulation Kit](https://pyreos.com/evaluation-kits/)

(8) [MCP3008 10 Bit ADC Raspberry Pi Python Library 0.1a3 (pip install mcp3008) - PiPy.org](https://pypi.org/project/mcp3008/)

(9) [MCP3008/MCP3201/MCP3208 10-bit/12-bit ADC Rpi Python Programming / Demo Program / Q&A - tlfong01, EESE 2020aug06](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/515225/spi-slave-randomly-missing-bits-in-response)

(10) [A Review on Forest Fire Detection Techniques - Ahmad A. A. AlkhatibFirst Published March 4, 2014 Review Article](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1155/2014/597368)

(11) [32/64/128/256/512/1024/2048/4096 Point FFT Core - IPCores](http://www.ipcores.com/FFT4096.htm?gclid=Cj0KCQiAv6yCBhCLARIsABqJTjYSun-kuq85ESUiXAn4RIX-W99DDSt0VrKZwgf1U1J5oeOEw6ZDkjwaAngFEALw_wcB)

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - Pyroelectric Flame Sensor PY-ITV Datasheet Summary*

*Introduction*

The Pyreos thin film pyroelectric infrared flame detectors offer exceptionally high responsivity, a wide field of view of typically 100° (*subject to filter band pass specification) and class leading rapid recovery from thermal and electrical shocks (<1 second downtime). This current mode sensor has excellent
signal to noise at the signature 8-10 Hz flicker range of a flame, and can provide accurate discrimination of flame sources in triple IR flame detection systems.

The sensor element is built into a low noise circuit that has an internal CMOS op amp with a 10GΩ feedback resistor outputting a voltage signal centred around
half the supply rail.

---

*Sensor Characteristics*

Filter aperture = 5.2 mm x 4.2 mm

Element size = 1000 µm x 1000 µm

Package = TO39

Responsivity = 1 150,000 V/W

D* = 3.5 x 108 cm√Hz/ W

Noise = Mean 70 µV√Hz

Field of View = Typical 100°

---

*Electrical Characteristics*

Max. Voltage (+V) = 8.0 V

Min. Voltage (+V) = 2.7 V

Output voltage normalised around mid-rail

Time Constant = ~12 ms

Operating Temperature = -40 to +85 °C

Storage Temperature = -40 to +110 °C

Op-Amp with 10 GΩ feedback resistor

Filter As per Filters Available table

---

*Appendix B - Package Info and Internal Schematic*

[image: package info and schematic]

---

*Appendix C - Example Raw Data for FFT*

[image: example raw data]

---

*Appendix D - Rigol DS1504Z 50MHz 1Gsp/s Scope 1KHz square wave signal FFT Test*

[image: fft test]

*/ to continue, ...*

---