# how can i connect a Non-invasive AC Current Sensor Split Core Transformer 100A or 30A to Raspberry-pi 4,

Tags: pi-4, lcd, connectors

were you able to make it work ? I'm looking to display Current, voltage and Power through an LCD 16x2 screen using Raspberry Pi 4.I'm looking into what kind of current sensor i should use to measure AC current and have it displayed. 
Please let me know you can up with any solutions.

Comment: You might like to read the chat record of the following question on AC current measurement: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106761/interpreting-voltage-output-on-adc-with-rated-ac-current-sensor.

Comment: `were you able to make it work ?` ... who are you talking to?