# Interfacing non bluetooth speaker with Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, hardware, audio, power, speakers

I want a wired connection between speaker and Raspberry pi 3 Model B. Bluetooth or Wireless connection is not my requirement.

Regarding my speaker - it should NOT simply output buzzer sounds but is capable of producing human voice/ music.

I have researched on this and have come to know that I would be connecting the speaker to the audio Jack provided on the Raspberry Pi 3 board. But direct connection won't be enough. There would be a need of an amplifier between audio jack and the speaker.

I want to know (to summarize):

1. Exact names of chip/ IC that are needed.
2. Circuit connection. Circuit diagram.
3. Speaker specifications. Any low quality speaker that can be
   interfaced with Raspberry pi 3     3.5 mm Jack.

Comment: your question is not related to the Raspberry Pi ... try posting here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Hi @NeedSomeLuck, Welcome and Nice to meet you.  Ah, let me see. For Rpi audio newbies, I would recommend the PAM8610 power amplifier.  I used it with Rpi 3.5mm jack, and also USB sound stick, both working well with Rpi3B+. Any cheapy speaker (4/8/16Ω) are OK. References: AliExpress DC12V 15W + 15W PAM8610 Digital HiFi Power Amplifier US$8 / to continue, ...

Comment: AliExpress 12V 15Wx2 PAM8610 Power Amplifier - US$8
(1) https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32828586240.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.49.3c7422fdynOucR&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_10068_319_5735015_317_5734915_10696_10084_453_10924_454_10083_10618_10920_10921_10307_10922_537_536_10059_10884_10887_100031_5735215_321_322_10103_5735115,searchweb201603_51,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=313c57d7-aac8-47a4-a578-88810d9ecbfe-7&algo_pvid=313c57d7-aac8-47a4-a578-88810d9ecbfe
(2) Power Amp PAM8610 Forum Discussion
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=224976&start=25#p1396404

Comment: You may also like to consider Rpi compatible USB sound/card/stick (so you can also record audio using a cheapy piezo microphone later). The USB sound stick is much more HIFi than Rpi's stupid, ugly looking, 3.5mm audio/composite video jack: (2) Power Amp PAM8610 Forum Discussion
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=224976&start=25#p1396404
(3) USB Sound Stick Forum Discussion
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=224976&sid=7efb7d0a272a6689a6e1480606e6e2e1#p1383138. Happy HiFi listening.  Cheers.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention one thing about some of the Rpi GPIO features of modern day audio power amps. (1) The usually have "shutdown", "standby" digital inputs, so can use Rpi GPIO pins (some requires converting to 5V, some are 5V tolerant) to do shut down or standby, to get rid the the annoying "squeking" sound. (2) Most of the cheapie (around US$1) are no longer the old days A/B circuit, but are D type, or digital type, meaning that the input audio analog signal is chopped and sampled, then using digital signal processing techniques to filter unwanted > 40kHz band, / to continue, ...

Comment: Or do audio quality control, like heavy bass etc, as described in the USB audio sound stick spec. Another thing Rpi audio newbies can play with is the digital volume control, in say 40 steps, so Rpi can use a cheapy US$1 DAC to do fade in, fade out effects. The PAM8610 board I recommended above is DIY version, so it is easy to tear down and hack.

Comment: The OP wishes to know cheap audio IC and speaker spec.  As I said earlier, all cheap speaker will do, all cheap electrec microphone will do (expensive dynamic, moving coils actually do not work well with Rpi ALSA library).  To control amp volume, I would recommend: I2C PCF8591 8-bit ADC/DAC module - US$1
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32891915230.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.19807be81a2m0h&algo_pvid=b01e9810-b150-4ffd-9221-0bdcb63c7316&algo_expid=b01e9810-b150-4ffd-9221-0bdcb63c7316-2&btsid=0ab6f83115821697994952425e25ed&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

Comment: I recently noticed the Audino guys are catching up Rpi audio software, so perhaps Rpi guys should also catching up Arduino audio hardware: Reference:How to use Rpi python to control PCM1802 24-bit HiFi stereo ADC and MAX4466 microphone amplifier
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107778/how-to-use-rpi-python-to-control-pcm1802-24-bit-hifi-stereo-adc-and-max4466-micr. Cheers.