# Is there any sound card or ADC for Raspberry Pi 4 available in the market?

Tags: python

The currently used sound card is "HIFIBERRY DAC+ ADC", I want to use the ADC function to recover the "modulated carrier signal (PSK, FSK)", because the "gnuradio" block currently used requires linux ALSA can only be used after detection. Is there an integrated ADC or sound card that can be used for Raspberry Pi and the driver has been written??

Comment: You can use most USB audio devices, which are widely and cheaply available.  However, I suspect what you are wanting to do (it is not clear) can't be done from userspace, you would have to do some kernel hacking.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help, but the sampling rate of commercially available sound cards is too low for me, the sampling rate I need is at least close to 200Ksps, there is no ability to modify the kernel at present, I would like to ask if there is a direct and complete one set?

Comment: why is this information missing from your question?

Comment: This might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107778/how-to-use-rpi-python-to-control-pcm1802-24-bit-hifi-stereo-adc-and-max4466-micr