# is it possible to connect a USB microphone to Pi Pico

Tags: usb, pi-pico, microphone, usb-audio

I am attempting to do some real-time audio processing using the Pi Pico. I know that a MEMS microphone can be connected and used for this purpose (see [here](https://www.hackster.io/sandeep-mistry/create-a-usb-microphone-with-the-raspberry-pi-pico-cc9bd5#:%7E:text=We%20can%20use%20it%27s%20built,into%20a%20USB%20microphone%20device.) and [here](https://www.hackster.io/AlexWulff/adc-sampling-and-fft-on-raspberry-pi-pico-f883dd)). However, I need to use an analog microphone that runs through an XLR cable to an ADC preamp and out into a USB format. Is connecting this to the Pi Pico possible and how could I go about this? Could I skip the preamp and connect the mic directly to the ADC pins of the Pi Pico? Or is there some expansion board that would support connecting a USB mic directly to the Pico? Bonus if you could help me understand how I2S would fit into this picture, if at all. Thanks!

Comment: You need USB host code to handle USB devices, maybe https://github.com/hathach/tinyusb. The signal level of a mic is probably too low for an ADC pin. I think you would need an analog preamp. (Some protective circuitry for your input pins is also recommended.)

Comment: This might help: ***Create a USB Microphone with the Raspberry Pi Pico*** - Sandeep Mistry 2021may20
https://www.hackster.io/sandeep-mistry/create-a-usb-microphone-with-the-raspberry-pi-pico-cc9bd5

Comment: Thanks. I read through this page, but it is specifically about connecting analog and PDM mics to the Pico and transferring that data using USB, whereas I would like the Pico to itself accept a USB input. I think this is the concept of USB host referenced in the top comment.

Comment: Or this might help: 
How to use Rpi python to control ***PCM1802 24-bit HiFi stereo ADC and MAX4466 microphone amplifier***, Asked 2 years, 10 months ago
Modified 1 year, 8 months ago Viewed 3k times
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107778/how-to-use-rpi-python-to-control-pcm1802-24-bit-hifi-stereo-adc-and-max4466-micr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you would need to be a USB host and support UAC2.  The driver that the raspberry pi pico has is tiny USB and that currently doesn't support UAC2 in host mode.  You can be a device, so you could be a mic.  But there's not drivers to have a usb mic connect to the raspberry pi pico currently.